# How to hide the treeview parent and child nodes in WPF Treeview

Tags: wpf

We have got a treeview and we are adding the parent and child nodes in the design time.In the run time we would like to hide and show the parent and child nodes in the WPF Treeview. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here the First XAML Code

```
<TreeView Height="183" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  >
                <TreeViewItem Header="USA" Name="USA">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Item a" />
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Item b" />
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Item c" />
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="UK" Name="UK">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Item a" />
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Item b" />
                </TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="German" Name="German">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Item a" />
                </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

And Here how to Expand and collapse the TreeView in Code.

```
   private void HideParent()
    {
        USA.IsExpanded= false;
    }
```

In here USA means Parent TreeViewItem.